# VS Code not processing python print commands after input

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

The below python code works perfectly well in Visual Studio and Python IDLE. But when I write it in VISUAL STUDIO CODE, all the 4 print commands that come after the input value are not processed.

```
print ('hello world') 
print ('hello world') 
message = raw_input ('type message ') 
print ('message') 
print ('statement 1') 
print ('statement 2') 
print ('statement 3') 
print ('statement 4')
```

For example, when I fill in the input with "my message", it just prints:

```
hello world
hello world
type message 
my message
```

And doesn´t execute the 4 print commands that come after the input. 
The expected output would be:

```
hello world
hello world
type message 
my message
statement 1
statement 2
statement 3
statement 4
```

Any idea why Visual Studio Code does not process the remaining 4 print commands?

Answer (score 1):

It works fine with my VS. One thing I think you are trying to do is to print user input with this command.

print ('message')

so it would be

print message

Comment: Thanks guys, for your contributions. In fact, the error is not in the code, but in the fact that VSC does not support direct input from the output window. I just figured out the solution. See below ....

Answer (score 1):

I just found it out myself. 
The Debug Console **does not support programs that need to read input** from the console, but you can enable an external, native console by setting the attribute externalConsole to true in your launch configuration.
launch.json - "externalConsole" : true

Answer (score 0):

Isn't there a plugin you could add to VS Code to strictly code in Python? Also ... I strongly suggest using Adobe Brackets. I use it as my main tool when programming anything. [Brackets](http://www.brackets.io)